# StandardJS VSCode extension no longer highlighting errors - suddenly stopped working

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, standardjs

I've been using the Standard VSCode extension to highlight StandardJS linting errors in some folders in a workspace that has multiple folders representing different repos with different coding styles. It had worked well for over a year, but it stopped showing any syntax highlighting on September 10th, 2021.

I have checked the extension is still enabled and that the `standard` engine in in my `devDependencies` and working from the CLI with `npx standard`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [recent release](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/standard.vscode-standard/changelog#user-content-2.0.0) changed the default behavior for workspaces with multiple folders. you must now set `"standard.enableGlobally": true` in your VSCode settings.json or check the related box in the extension settings GUI.